# Django - How to extend a form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-haystack

I'm new to Django. I have installed an external App that is in "python2.6/site-packages/haystack". This external App have "generic forms" but I need to add a CSS class that is not in the "generic form".

How can I extend the "forms.py" the "class FacetedModelSearchForm" from the "generic form" to "forms.py" in my own App?

Here is the code from the "generic form"

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_('Search'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.searchqueryset = kwargs.pop('searchqueryset', None)
        self.load_all = kwargs.pop('load_all', False)

        if self.searchqueryset is None:
            self.searchqueryset = SearchQuerySet()

        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def no_query_found(self):
        """
        Determines the behavior when no query was found.
        By default, no results are returned (``EmptySearchQuerySet``).
        Should you want to show all results, override this method in your
        own ``SearchForm`` subclass and do ``return self.searchqueryset.all()``.
        """
        return EmptySearchQuerySet()

    def search(self):
        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()

        if not self.cleaned_data.get('q'):
            return self.no_query_found()

        sqs = self.searchqueryset.auto_query(self.cleaned_data['q'])

        if self.load_all:
            sqs = sqs.load_all()

        return sqs

    def get_suggestion(self):
    if not self.is_valid():
        return None

    return self.searchqueryset.spelling_suggestion(self.cleaned_data['q'])


class FacetedSearchForm(SearchForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.selected_facets = kwargs.pop("selected_facets", [])
    super(FacetedSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def search(self):
    sqs = super(FacetedSearchForm, self).search()

    # We need to process each facet to ensure that the field name and the
    # value are quoted correctly and separately:
    for facet in self.selected_facets:
        if ":" not in facet:
            continue

        field, value = facet.split(":", 1)

        if value:
            sqs = sqs.narrow(u'%s:"%s"' % (field, sqs.query.clean(value)))

    return sqs
```

How can I add to the field "q" the CSS class "myspecialcssclass" extending this class in my App "forms.py"? The class that I need to extend is the "FacetedSearchForm". Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm

class CustomSearchForm(FacetedSearchForm)
    q = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Search', widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={"class":"myspecialcssclass",}))
```

your custom form must be set in your haystack urls e.g:

```
from haystack.views import SearchView

urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^$', SearchView(form_class=CustomSearchForm, results_per_page=20), name='haystack_search'),
)
```

Also see the haystack [views and forms documentation](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/views_and_forms.html#creating-your-own-form)

Answer (score 2):

I think this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances

might help.

Basically, you need to subclass `FacetedSearchForm` and add an argument to you widget

```
class MyForm(FacetedSearchForm):
    q = forms.CharField(
            required=False,
            label='Search',
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'myspecialcssclass'}))
```

And that should be it.

Answer (score 1):

The form field widget `attrs` maps html attributes to their values. Override these attributes in a subclasses `__init__` function to safely modify the field.

```
class MyForm(FacedSearchForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['q'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'myspecialcssclass'
```